# Kinect show Depth Image in Full Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

Is there a way to show Kinect Depth Image into Full Screen mode? I'm using C# and WPF, the OpenNI C++ example able to show the dept image in full size with out any stretch occur, but when I use WPF, the image gets stretch out.

Currently I'm getting resolution of 640X480, but I want to display it into any screen size or maybe TV. My laptop is 1280X768 but when u make the image full size it get stretced.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using the SDK, or the beta?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the **hardware** resolution of the [Kinect cameras is 640 x 480](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect#Technology) so there is no way to increase that without stretching.

In WPF it is possible to scale the image in proportion so the dots of the image remain square.

```
<Image Source="..." Stretch="Uniform" />
```

or not scale at all:

```
<Image Source="..." Stretch="None" />
```

See Stretching Images under [Displaying Images in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx#_displayingimages)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, I have tried that, but I hope to make the image cover whole screen with any stretch, like the sample provided by OpenNI, where they render the Dept Image in full screen but without any stretch...Probably is there a way to adjust the pixel?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make much sense to me. The camera can only give you 640x480 so if your screen's resolution is bigger than that you will have to stretch the image. The only other option is to change the resolution of the screen. What do you mean by adjusting the pixel?